# Downloading a file using wget

Tags: download, wget

I'm trying to download a program from a website using wget. However, whenever I try to download it I instead get a HTML file. I'm using the following syntax.

```
wget http://domain.com/downloads/name/
```

If you go the link directly the browser automatically tries to download the file. Why is that I'm getting the HTML file instead of the actual file I want?

Comment: what happen when you open the url normally, is it giving the file to download or html page?

Comment: it takes you to a html page and then you see a countdown clock..when the countdown clock reaches 0 I get a popup asking me if I want to save or run the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think wget can get the file for you like this, it will just get you the first page html, your page has some delaying code,  and not a direct url to the file, so you will need a real browser to download the file

Comment: Since that file is trying to download automatically, does that mean the file is located in that folder?

Comment: it may be anywhere on the server, may be outside the website folder and some where else, and may be on another server as well