# Downloading a large file using wget on a server

Tags: html, unix, server, download, wget

I'm new to unix based OS and learned that curl or wget commands gets data from a given url. When I tried the command:

```
wget https://www.nitrc.org/frs/downloadlink.php/3417
```

which is a 2GB fMRI file from ADHD200 dataset (https://www.nitrc.org/frs/?group_id=383), I get a 38,2KB file consisting of an HTML code i guess. I searched for a similar case ([downloading-a-file-using-wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127549/downloading-a-file-using-wget) yet I understand that only a browser could download from such link. Since being connected to a Intel Xeon Cluster, I cannot use a browser from command line nor use sudo commands.

Downloading a data should not be this difficult. Am I missing something. Tried several flags such as

```
wget -O filename.tar.gz https://www.nitrc.org/frs/downloadlink.php/3417
```

and

```
wget --trust-server-names https://www.nitrc.org/frs/downloadlink.php/3417
```

or using python scripts, yet still the same small file.

Comment: Have you tried the URL in your browser? It asks you to sign in...

Comment: It automatically starts downloading. Perhaps cuz i am already logged in